# Were the Wakanda scenes filmed at the same time?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, production, avengers-infinity-war, black-panther

*Black Panther* took place primarily in Wakanda, and the climax/ending of Avengers: Infinity War also took place there.

Many of the actors, backgrounds, costumes, CGI, and presumably filming location(s) would be the same for these scenes. It would make sense for Black Panther's production to simply keep everybody in wardrobe and makeup and film the scenes for Infinity War as well. Did they take advantage of this?

Answer (score 9):

Possibly yes.

From [this article](https://www.atlasofwonders.com/2018/04/avengers-infinity-war-filming-locations.html),

> Producers requested African actors for the battle scene filmed at Bouckaert Farms in Fairburn (Georgia). **This are the same fields used in Black Panther, both films were shot at the same time.** These sequences were completed in post-production adding an African landscape and the city of Wakanda to the background.

From [this interview of Ryan Coogler](https://io9.gizmodo.com/how-the-teams-behind-black-panther-and-infinity-war-wor-1822666366),

> “So what [Infinity War directors the Russo Brothers] would do is, they would send their production design team and their VFX team to come spend time with me and our production design and VFX team,” Black Panther co-writer and director Ryan Coogler told io9 this week. “And they would ask questions. Even with their writers [Christopher Markus and Stephen McFeely], as they were writing, they were thinking about, ‘What scene does this?’ ‘What kind of things in the Wakanda that you are building have these things?’ ‘Where would this kind of thing happen?’ So as we were really fleshing out Wakanda, we would tell them all about it so that their ideas could track.”
>
> The same went for the actors who appear in both films. “**[The Infinity War team] would spend time with our actors when they could, just so they could get ready to do what they need to do in their film**,” Coogler said.

Comment: I appreciate this good answer! Though I'm not 100% sure of the integrity of the first article, the 2nd seems to point towards yes. However the quote(s) you provided do not necessarily say they did those scenes at the same time, just that the directors and actors collaborated.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for more authoritative source.

Comment: Hmmm...Wikipedia would seem to indicate that BP ending filming in Georgia by April 2017 but IW didn't start there until June 2017 but that doesn't mean there wasn't overlap